# Can Envoy interpret wasm or is wasm opaque to it?

Tags: emscripten, envoyproxy, wasm-bindgen

Can the proxy ENVOY interpret wasm files? Like are the wasm files transparent to the envoy? I used a wasm filter which changes the http header with envoy and did a curl to it to capture the http header and its showing the interpreted version of wasm not the binary. It does mean that envoy interprets wasm, just wanted to confirm. Sources are so low on these.

Answer (score 2):

Envoy documentation for WASM is lacking mostly because support is not fully baked yet.  That said, I'm not really sure I understand what you have tried nor the expected results.

The intent of a WASM filter is to allow developers to add Envoy filters without:

- Recompiling Envoy or
- Writing the filter in C++.

It is not to deliver WASM content to a client for use by that client. Though you could write a WASM filter that does that and perhaps you have.

But in the intended flow, Envoy runs one or more WASM virtual machines that load the compiled WASM binary files from local disk or URL and adds them to the filter stack.  Those filters are then invoked and perform some action on requests and responses.

So right now I assume you have:

1. Compiled a [version](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy-wasm) of Envoy that supports WASM filters
2. Written a WASM filter in the language of your choice and compiled ([C++](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy-wasm/tree/master/examples/wasm)).
3. Configured Envoy to [use](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy-wasm/blob/master/examples/wasm/envoy.yaml#L26) your filter.
4. Started Envoy and made requests that would be impacted by the filter.

If you have done all of the above, the only way that the header set by your filter would contain "WASM" is if you populated a header with "WASM" in the filter. If this is in fact what you have done, you should be aware that header size is not infinite and any non-trival WASM filter will present size issues.